# How to focus same input after onSubmitEditing?

Tags: forms, react-native

I want to focus again to the same input after onSubmitEditing function. But couldn't achieve yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<Input
       ref='barcode'
       style={styles.barcodeInput}
       autoFocus={true}
       onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({barcodeNumber: text});
       }}
       onSubmitEditing={(event)=> {
          this.getResult();
       }}
       placeholder='Barcode Number'/>

getResult(){
    if ( this.state.barcodeNumber === '021200507878' ){
        this.setState({backgroundColor: '#2ecc71', status:'success'});//green

    } else {
        this.setState({backgroundColor: '#c0392b', status:'error'}); //red
    }

    this.clearText('barcode');
}

clearText(fieldName) {

   this.refs[fieldName].setNativeProps({text: ''});
}
```

I know how to do it by button or by other input field's submit. But i can not do it with the same input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, how fool i am. Just add the below line into the TextInput will work.

```
blurOnSubmit={false}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**Docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html), it states:

> Two methods exposed via the native element are `.focus()` and `.blur()` that will focus or blur the `TextInput` programmatically.

Therefore, this should work:

```
// create your ref object somewhere global
let barcode: Input;

// then this should work
<Input
       ref={this.barcode}
       style={styles.barcodeInput}
       autoFocus={true}
       onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({barcodeNumber: text});
       }}
       onSubmitEditing={(event)=> {
          this.getResult();
          this.barcode.focus();
       }}
       placeholder='Barcode Number'/>

getResult(){
    if ( this.state.barcodeNumber === '021200507878' ){
        this.setState({backgroundColor: '#2ecc71', status:'success'});//green

    } else {
        this.setState({backgroundColor: '#c0392b', status:'error'}); //red
    }

    this.clearText('barcode');
}

clearText(fieldName) {

   this.refs[fieldName].setNativeProps({text: ''});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort mate but this is not working :(

Comment: @burakkesepara What's not working? how and what did you try?

Comment: i have created my ref object under render()  function. Then did those things you said. But i get an error titled "Can not read property 'focus' of undefined".

Comment: @burakkesepara how I wrote it I believe is the right way to go, but what you are seeing is some different issue. It will help if you post how you implemented it maybe it is trying to call `focus` on the object before it the object is ready

Comment: thanks again bro but i found the solution. how fool i am :( adding just the blurOnSubmit={false} line will work for me.